# d3js: Calculating sub-totals, conditional on i=="some stuff"

Tags: d3.js

**Warning/Disclaimer**: This is a basic JavaScript question, but I've gone through a bunch of iterations in my code, much Googling, and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to proceed.

I have data in three columns in a CSV file: a political candidate's name, their party, and their approval rating.

I've created a bubble chart/force layout, similar to [this](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/02/13/us/politics/2013-budget-proposal-graphic.html?_r=0). Candidates are represented as bubbles. Users can select to see candidates organized in one big blob, or they can click to see the bubbles organize themselves by party. I have some `<div>` elements that pop up under each grouping of same-party candidates. What I'd like to do now is to have each party-specific `<div>` element display the total approval rating all its same-party candidates get, combined. (So, in Excel, a `=SUMIF()`.)

To do this: I'm creating a `function(party)` which should, in principle, return that conditional sum. Here's what it looks like when I'm calling it for candidates with no party affiliation:

```
        d3.select("#text-NONE")
                .text(label_party("N/A"));
```

"N/A" is the string found in the CSV file.

And the function itself:

```
        function label_party(party) {
            var party_total = 0;
            function party(d) {
            if (d.party[i] == "party") {
                party_total+= d.y2012[i];
            };
            };
            return party_total;
        };
```

Both of the above are happening outside of the `d3.csv()` call. My main Q: how can I set up a conditional sum over two columns in a CSV? At the moment, it's simply returning 0 - so it's skipping my loop, though I don't know why.

Comment: i'm a little confused if you mean for the (party) parameter to be used in d.party[i]. but you'll need to not use 'd', is my guess. instead use your data object from the csv function (say, data). then access the party with data['party'] and reassign it to data.

Comment: Thanks. Still messing around with it - no luck. I'm having trouble with calling the data I want: basically, when I'm outside of the `d3.csv()` call, I get an error where `d` is undefined (regardless of what I'm using as a parameter in `function(x)`). I'm unsure of how to call the data without using `d` (I've also tried calling the node objects themselves, which are stored in a var `nodes`). When I try sticking the function *within* the `d3.csv`, it breaks, telling me - at the `<div>` stage - that the function `label_party()` is undefined.